# ResultSet in a ObservableList

Tags: java, jdbc, javafx, netbeans

Here's my problem : 
I have a class Detenu :

```
public class Detenu {
    private static String n_ecrou;    // Unique id
    private static String prenom;
    private static String nom;
    private static String date_naissance;
    private static String lieu_naissance;

    public Detenu(String p1, String p2, String p3, String p4, String p5) {
        n_ecrou = p1;
        prenom = p2;
        nom = p3;
        date_naissance = p4;
        lieu_naissance = p5;
    }

    public static String getN_ecrou() {
        return n_ecrou;
    }
}
```

I also use JDBC to connect my application to an embedded database. This database implements a DETENU table with 5 columns, which are "N_ECROU", "PRENOM", "NOM", "DATE_NAISSANCE", "LIEU_NAISSANCE".

Then, I need to display all the Detenus stored in my database in a JavaFX TableView. So i use a getData() function like this :

```
public static ObservableList<Detenu> getData() {
    ObservableList<Detenu> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    try {
        // This part works fine
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("...");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM DETENU);

        while(result.next()) {
            // Here comes the problem
            // This shows all the different n_ecrou
            System.out.println(result.getObject(1).toString());

            data.add(new Detenu(result.getObject(1).toString(), result.getObject(2).toString(), result.getObject(3).toString(), result.getObject(4).toString(), result.getObject(5).toString()));
        }
        // This shows the same n_ecrou
        System.out.println(data.get(0).getN_ecrou() + " " + data.get(1).getN_ecrou());
        stmt.close();
        result.close();
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        //Error process
    }

    return data;
}
```

By exemple, i have two Detenus in my database. The ObservableList i get back contains two Detenus, but the same one, the last in the databse.
So when i want to display this data in a TableView, its creates two rows, but they are identical.
Show in picture :

[The database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHWrV.jpg) | 
[The TableView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POQeu.jpg)

I dont have any idea why this is happening so any help will be thanked :)

PS : sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All members of your `Detenu` class are `static` (shared by all instance of the class) that's why you have that behavior. Just remove the keyword on the fields and it should works.